# suPar constituency parser with POS tags

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I have trained a [SuPar Constituency Parser](https://pypi.org/project/supar/) with my own dataset. I have a POS tagger model, too. How can I get an output that shows POS tags in it? The supar constituency parser outputs a sentence tree without POS tags.
example:

```
>>> con = Parser.load('crf-con-en')
>>> con.predict(['I', 'saw', 'Sarah', 'with', 'a', 'telescope', '.'], verbose=False)[0].pretty_print()
              TOP                       
               |                         
           S                        
  _____________|______________________   
 |             VP                     | 
 |    _________|____                  |  
 |   |    |         PP                | 
 |   |    |     ____|___              |  
 NP  |    NP   |        NP            | 
 |   |    |    |     ___|______       |  
 _   _    _    _    _          _      _ 
 |   |    |    |    |          |      |  
 I  saw Sarah with  a      telescope  .
```

I know that there is a tag argument in the constituency parse model (which can be seen [here](https://github.com/yzhangcs/parser/blob/main/supar/models/const/crf/model.py)), but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Can you pass verbose=True to con.predict in the code snippet you provided?

Comment: @PeterBergman yes I can, but the result is same.

Comment: If you remove the pretty_print method call, it outputs a table with tags, correct? As I understand it, these tags are not POS (part of speech) tags. They include tags like "nsubj", which indicates "nominal subject", which is not a part of speech like noun or pronoun. @user3140519 can you confirm this?

Comment: Could you provide some more information about your tagger model? I think it would help to know the type of the POS tagger model. Any other information you could provide may help, too :)

Comment: Could you provide an example of an acceptable output for the sentence you provided?